# ClassCastException in JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, java-8, javafx-8, classcastexception

My code gets the following error.

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.ClassCastException: javafx.scene.Group cannot be cast to javafx.scene.control.TreeCell
```

**Source code**

```
private TreeItem getClickedTreeItem(EventTarget eventTarget){
    TreeItem clickedTreeItem = null;

    if(eventTarget instanceof TreeCellSkin){
        clickedTreeItem = (TreeItem) ((TreeCell) ((TreeCellSkin)eventTarget).getParent()).getTreeItem();
    }else if(eventTarget instanceof LabeledText){
        clickedTreeItem = (TreeItem) ((TreeCell) ((LabeledText)eventTarget).getParent().getParent()).getTreeItem();
    }else if(eventTarget instanceof ImageView){
        clickedTreeItem = (TreeItem) ((TreeCell) ((ImageView)eventTarget).getParent().getParent()).getTreeItem();
    }

    return clickedTreeItem;
}
```

The console says this line:

```
clickedTreeItem = (TreeItem) ((TreeCell) ((ImageView)eventTarget).getParent().getParent()).getTreeItem();
```

This is legacy code that worked with Java 6, but gives the above exception using Java8?

What could be causing the `ClassCastException` now, and how to fix it for Java8?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [javafx.scene.control.TableColumn cannot be cast to javafx.scene.control.TableColumn$CellDataFeatures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32398007/javafx-scene-control-tablecolumn-cannot-be-cast-to-javafx-scene-control-tablecol)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The current code is brittle as it relies on the internal structure of the `TreeCell`. Also, `TreeCellSkin`<sup>1</sup> and `LabeledText` are both internal classes. Internal code is subject to change without notice and without regards to third party reliance on it. Since this worked in Java 6 but not Java 8 I can only assume that the `ImageView`'s grandparent changed from being the `TreeCell` to being a `Group` between the two versions.

To fix this you *could* look into the implementation and see what you need to do so you reach the `TreeCell` again, but that wouldn't *really* solve the problem. The use of `EventTarget` says to me this code was implemented while not fully understanding how event handling works in JavaFX. From the apparent goal of this code you should be using the *source* of the event, not the *target*. In JavaFX, the source of the event is always the object for which the `EventHandler` currently handling said `Event` was added to<sup>2</sup>. In other words, if you added the `EventHandler` to the `TreeCell` then the source will be the `TreeCell`. Using the source, and assuming `EventHandler` is added to the `TreeCell`, you can simply do:

```
TreeItem<?> item = ((TreeCell<?>) event.getSource()).getTreeItem();
```

Of course, if you're adding the `EventHandler` to the `TreeCell` you likely needn't bother with the source as you'll have access to the `TreeCell` directly. For example:

```
TreeView<String> treeView = new TreeView<>();
treeView.setCellFactory(tv -> {
    TreeCell<String> cell = new TreeCell<>(); // or some custom implementation
    cell.setOnMouseClicked(event -> {
        TreeItem<String> item = cell.getTreeItem();
        // do something with item...
    });
    return cell;
});
```

---

<sup>1. `TreeCellSkin` became public API in JavaFX 9 along with many (all?) skin implementations. They are part of the `javafx.scene.control.skin` package.</sup>
<sup>2. There's more to it but that's beyond the scope of this answer.</sup>

Comment: Nice one here!!